# How to get related record from the parent table

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, bookshelf.js

I have two tables. users is a parent and leaves is a child table.
Every user has more than one leave requests. 
users.id is primary key and leaves.userID is foreign key.
**I want to get related user's record with the every leave record.**

Here is users model

```
import bookshelf from '../config/bookshelf';

const TABLE_NAME = 'users';

/**
 * User model.
 */
class User extends bookshelf.Model {

    /**
     * Get table name.
     */
    get tableName() {
        return TABLE_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Table has timestamps.
     */
    get hasTimestamps() {
        return true;
    }

    verifyPassword(password) {
        return this.get('password') === password;
    }
}

export default User;
```

Here is leaves model

```
import bookshelf from '../config/bookshelf';

const TABLE_NAME = 'leaves';

/**
 * Client model.
 */
class leaves extends bookshelf.Model {

    /**
     * Get table name.
     */
    get tableName() {
        return TABLE_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Table has timestamps.
     */
    get hasTimestamps() {
        return true;
    }

    verifyPassword(password) {
        return this.get('password') === password;
    }
}

export default leaves;
```

It is my code to fetch the leaves records.

```
leaves.forge()
        .fetchAll()
        .then(leaves => res.json({
                error: false,
                data: leaves.toJSON()
            })
        )
        .catch(err => res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                error: err
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless absolutely necessary, I don't recommend performing such a function in your application code. What you are asking is very rudimentary in the data world, and your DBMS will be far more capable of processing such a request. No need to slow down your app with a request that should be off-loaded to the DBMS. It's what the DBMS is made for. Don't reinvent the wheel.

If your DBMS supports Views, then create a View to perform this function. You could also do this in a Stored Procedure. It is a very simple JOIN query that can be done in as few as 3 lines of SQL code. After you have the View, your app can read data from it just like any other table.